# Rails 3 Not Logging in Development

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I've tried calling both `logger.debug` and `Rails.logger.debug` but nothing is getting outputted to the development.log file. Any ideas as to what's going?

**Update**

I should also note that I'm calling this from a controller and that other information such as the SQL queries are getting outputted to the log file.

**Source Code**

https://github.com/kyledecot/skateparks-web

**Gemfile**

```
source 'http://rubygems.org/'

gem 'rails', '3.0.7'
gem 'rake', '~> 0.8.7'
gem 'devise'
gem 'omniauth'
gem 'flash_cookie_session'
gem 'carrierwave'
gem 'mini_magick'
gem 'barometer'
gem 'gdata_19', :require => 'gdata'
gem 'google_places'
gem 'fleakr'
gem 'resque'
gem 'nokogiri'
gem 'decent_exposure'
gem 'cancan'
gem 'friendly_id'
gem 'breadcrumbs_on_rails'
gem 'defensio'
gem 'twitter'
gem 'thinking-sphinx', :require => 'thinking_sphinx'
gem 'ts-resque-delta', '1.0.0', :require => 'thinking_sphinx/deltas/resque_delta'
gem 'mime-types', :require => 'mime/types'
gem 'vpim'
gem 'will_paginate', '~> 3.0.pre2'
gem 'acts_as_geocodable'
gem 'acts_as_audited', '2.0.0.rc7'
gem 'passenger'
gem 'paper_trail'
gem 'thin'
gem 'compass', '>= 0.11.1'
gem 'guard-compass'
gem 'redcarpet'
gem 'mysql2', '0.2.7'
gem 'placemaker'

group :development, :test do

  gem 'sqlite3'
  gem 'capybara'  
  gem 'launchy'
  gem "rspec-rails"
  gem 'rb-fsevent', :require => false if RUBY_PLATFORM =~ /darwin/i
  gem 'guard-rspec'
  gem 'guard-bundler'
  gem 'guard-delayed'
  gem 'factory_girl'
  gem 'rspec'

end

group :production do 
end
```

**enviornment.rb**

```
require File.expand_path('../application', __FILE__)
Skateparks::Application.initialize!
ActiveRecord::Base.logger.level = Logger::INFO
```

**ImagesController**

```
def server
  logger.warn "WARN!" # nothing
  logger.info "INFO!" # nothing
  logger.debug "DEBUG!" # nothing
  puts Rails.logger.inspect # shows
  puts "PUTS!" # shows
end
```

**Log Output w/ `rails s`**

```
#<ActiveSupport::BufferedLogger:0x000001058867a0 @level=0, @buffer={}, @auto_flushing=1, @guard=#<Mutex:0x000001058866b0>, @log=#<File:/Users/Kyle/Desktop/skateparks-web/log/development.log>>
PUTS!


Started GET "/images/fd3b38315c30532b3a55bb84d35e5925/34_m.png" for 127.0.0.1 at 2011-06-29 03:41:50 -0400
  User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`id` = 1 LIMIT 1
```

Comment: We'll need atleast some code, you given us absolutely no information.

Comment: Are you sure you're running in the development environment?

Comment: Yes I'm sure I'm running in development mode. I've updated my answer to provide additional information.

Comment: Do you get output with logger.info or logger.warn?

Comment: No output w/ `info` or `warn`.

Comment: Any logger-related entries in config/environments/development.rb?  Such as config.logger or config.log_level settings?

Comment: The only place that config.logger and config.log_level is listed is in my production.rb file and it's commented out.

Comment: Whats the output of  "puts Rails.logger.inspect"?

Comment: #<ActiveSupport::BufferedLogger:0x0000010245e900 @level=1, @buffer={}, @auto_flushing=1, @guard=#<Mutex:0x0000010245e8b0>, @log=#<File:/Users/Kyle/Desktop/skateparks-web/log/development.log>>

Comment: Did you call `puts Rails.logger.inspect` from `def server`? Also, why is the sample output of the `GET` cycle not showing the string `PUTS!`?

Comment: Yes I called it form `def server`. It's not showing PUTS! in my sample as I posted that before trying `puts`. I'll update the sample.

Comment: And if you call `logger.flush` after a `logger.debug`, does output show up? And is possibly your code or some plugin you're using, redefining the `Logger` class?

Comment: What if you make a new app, using all the same gems/plugins as your current app, but with none of the code in your current app - does logging work then? And try also a `logger.info` in the console (`rails c`)?

Comment: I hope you're restarting the app after making changes to log level(just to be sure!). Also, does adding `ActiveRecord::Base.logger.level = Logger::INFO` in the config file at the end of `config/environment.rb` have any effect (or setting `ActiveRecord::Base.logger.level = 0`) ?

Comment: when calling `logger.flush` I get the following error: `undefined method `flush' for #<LoggerStub:0x00000104f2c1a0>`

Comment: are you sure you are calling `server` method? Your log shows database queries and unless you are calling `server` from inside another method, this will not happen since `server` does not have any query building statements.

Comment: Try setting the log level as I mentioned in previous comment..

Comment: I tried setting the logger level and restarting my server. Still nothing. Also, I know that I am calling the server method as my `puts` statement is being outputted with no problems.

Comment: Are you confusing the development.log file with the server console output?

Comment: I'm looking at both. I'm looking at `/log/development.log` and in the terminal.

Comment: Feel free to look at all of my code at https://github.com/kyledecot/skateparks-web

Comment: The "LoggerStub" error is curious.... I don't know whether that points at Rspec doing something bad to the app, or if it's a red herring :-/

Comment: Final guess... permissions. Delete the log file; check the permissions on the log folder is full control/777 everyone (or at least for the user running the server/apache) and restart... It should recreate the log file and populate it.

Comment: Try to take out any rspec related gems out of your :development group in your Gemfile. I think the logger got replaced by something test related.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## UPDATE:

Viget Labs has removed the loggable gem from their repo (
https://github.com/vigetlabs/loggable
)

---

Some gem in your app is using the [vigetlabs/loggable](https://github.com/vigetlabs/loggable) gem.
Looking at `Gemfile.lock`, it appears that the "fleakr" gem is using it.

> I noted that while `logger.info "hello"` does not work, `Rails.logger.info "hello"` works just fine.

It *appears* the loggable gem is somehow redefining the logger methods to do nothing using the `LoggerStub`:

```
class LoggerStub
  
  [:debug, :error, :fatal, :info, :warn].each do |method|
    class_eval <<-CODE
      def #{method}(message); nil; end
    CODE
  end
  
end
```

What is happening is that the loggable gem is defining a class variable and instance variable called `logger`, and the `.info` etc methods are being called on one of them. And those methods simply return `nil`.

I know this is a partial answer (in that it is not a complete solution), but that should be
good information to get you started on finding the proper solution.

Take a look also at these files:

1. [log_methods.rb](https://github.com/vigetlabs/loggable/blob/master/lib/loggable/log_methods.rb)
2. [logger_stub.rb](https://github.com/vigetlabs/loggable/blob/master/lib/loggable/logger_stub.rb)

**UPDATE**

Adding..

```
class ActionController::Base
    self.class.logger = Rails.logger
end
```

..should forcibly override loggable's assignment of the logger and things *should* work normally. I suppose the same would work for `class ActiveRecord::Base`.

But of course, this is a brute force solution that does not fix the underlying problem. For a real "fix" you would need to delve further into fleakr or loggable and maybe ask about this problem at the issues page for those gems.

**UPDATE**

See if you can make the fleakr gem use the [loggable fork from mediashelf](https://github.com/mediashelf/loggable/blob/master/lib/loggable/log_methods.rb#L20) : that fork should use the default Rails logger if it is available.

Comment: IMHO He should split the gems for :development and :test environments.

Comment: Fleaker was indeed the culprit. THANK YOU!

Comment: This wasn't my issue but it led me to the solution. For me it was the `rails_12factor` gem that heroku suggests. I didn't have it set to the production group and it has some kind of stdout logging gem included. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you're calling :GET "/images/92131721fcf3b8beb12b6e55014b9976/41_m.png"

...isn't that going to be going to the :show action in the images controller, rather than the :index?

(of course, I can't know for sure without knowing your routes file...)

Comment: It's actually going to a :server action which is a action I have setup for resizing and displaying different images

Comment: But your 'logger.warn "WARN!" # nothing' example shows it in :index... if that's not your real code structure, it just confuses people trying to help solve it

Comment: Thanks for the downvote, even though it *did* help correct the question }:-|

Comment: It didn't however solve the problem I'm having which is the real issue at hand, not the name of my class method is irrelevant.

Comment: It strikes me that something that gets you closer to solving your real problem (by making your question clearer) is more useful than less, even if it isn't a done-and-dusted finished answer.

Comment: @kyle..you are not supposed to downvote an answer because it didnt solve the problem...no one can guarantee their answer is going to solve the problem...in this case, @pavling was guessing your problem, as you gave absolutely nothing in the question, the first time

Comment: You're welcome. And though your answer helped making the question clearer, I think it would have been better as a comment.

Comment: @pavling..if you are unsure, always go for a comment rather than answering it..and in the comment ask for more details

Comment: @Zabba - Yes, I did consider a comment, but I thought there was a fair chance that the OP was just putting the logger tests in the wrong method. Anyhoo - I don't want to distract any further from any other attempts at answering the question. Cheers!